# Sticky navbar needs to occupy space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm trying to create a fixed navbar with the MaterializeCSS pushpin plugin. So far it's working fine, although when it snaps to the top of the page (= gets the position:fixed state), the content of the page gets pushed under the navbar.

Of course I could use a margin on my content, but then the content will also have that margin when the navbar isn't pinned.

Check https://eastsidetothewebsite.nl/edlifecoaching/ for an example.

How can I use the MaterializeCSS Pushpin plugin without the content falling up every time it's being pinned?

Comment: Presumably you're using JavaScript to change some styles to snap it to the top of the window. Could you not also change some styles to add the margin?

Comment: I've added a margin to the top element of the page (after the header) when the navbar gets fixed. I had to dig in the javascript file of the framework and edit it, which is not something I like to do but it solved the problem :)

Comment: Cool. I'll turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript changes some styles to snap it to the top of the window. You could change some styles to add the margin at the same time.